# Error exportar modulos en javascript y al utilizar require()

Tags: javascript, module.exports, requirejs

Tengo estructuradu mi projecto de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces, en mi archivo **pedido.js** tengo el siguiente codigo

```
async function getUser(token){
    try{
        const response = await fetch("/read-infoUser", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                "authorization": token
            }
        })
        if(response.ok){
            const data = await response.json()
            return data
        }
    }catch(err){
        console.log('Error al hacer el fetch en getUser -> ', err)
    }
}
async function getPostCar(idUser){
    try{
        const response = await fetch("/read-car",{
            method: "POST",
            headers:{
                "Content-Type":"application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({idUser})
        })
        if(response.ok){
            const data = await response.json()
            return data
        }
    }catch(err){
        console.log("Error en el fetch de getCar -> ", err)
    }
}
async function getPostCarPro(idCar) {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('/read-carPro', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ idCar })
        })
        if (response.ok) {
            const data = await response.json()
            return data
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error an el fetch de gePostCarPro -> ",err)
    }
}
async function putCar(idCar){
    try{
        const response = await fetch("/update-car", {
            method: "PUT",
            headers:{
                "Content-Type":"application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({idCar})
        })
        if(response.ok){
            const data = await response.json()
            return data
        }
    }catch(err){
        console.log("Error al ahcer el fetch en putCar carrito -> ", err)
    }
}
async function putPedido(idPedido, date, metodo, state, total){
    try{
        const response = await fetch("/update-pedido", {
            method:"PUT",
            headers:{
                "Content-Type":"application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({idPedido, date, metodo, state, total})
        })
        if(response.ok){
            const data = await response.json()
            return data
        }
    }catch(err){
        console.log("Error al hacer el fetch putPedido en carrito -> ",err)
    }
}

module.exports = {
    getUser,
    getPostCar,
    getPostCarPro,
    putCar,
    putPedido
}
```

Y cuando por ejemplo en mis archivos **header.js** o **carrito.js** o **En cualquier otro archivo js que tengo en el directorio** intento realizar
`const { getUser, getPostCar, putCar, putPedido} = require("./peticiones.js")`

Me dice que **getUser, getPostCar, putCar, putPedido** ya existe y `require()` no esta definido entonces borro toda la linea de `require()` y me funciona sin necesidad de hacer el `require()`

**ERRORES**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy utlizando mi proyecto con `Express` entonces mi pregunta es la siguiente

**¿Puedo dejarlo sin utilizar el `require()`? o me afectara al momento de correr mi servidor? tengo que solucionar eso? esta bien que ocurra eso que me esta pasando? y si tengo que solucionarlo, como podria hacerlo? o dado el caso, puedo hacerlo de otra manera?**

Comment: Hola, podrias añadir el error?

Comment: @Richi ya he agregado los errore muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Asumo que en tu html cargas todos los scripts, lo que significa que todas las funciones declaradas de manera pública en cualquiera de tus scripts ya estará disponible en los que se carguen a continuación. Por cierto, en navegador no existe `require`, es parte de node (js de servidor) con lo cual en los scripts que cargues en tu html NO puedes usar require.

Comment: @Benito-B
En mi html solamente estoy cargando el html de `index.js` y el `header.js` los demas son cargados dinamicamente a medida que se cambia de direccion para acceder a otro html
y en **peticiones.js** es donde realizo las peticiones y ese archivo yo no lo llamo en ningun lado